# Where to write java code in Android app

Tags: java, android

I just started learning how to create Android app and I'm stuck with methods in MainActivity.java. I don't know where to write my java code because the app is crashing.

```
package com.cidecode.loveometer;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=it Start from here.

Comment: Go through some basics on the official dev site. And learn how to use a debugger, it will greatly improve your ability to develop apps. It's often enough to simply read the logcat/print some stuff though.

Comment: I read that and other 3-4 tutorial on net and they are all diferent. Can you tell my just in what method to write code?

Comment: You should really just go through the tutorials on the official site like @MarcoAcierno suggested. Without any basic understanding how things work in Android you won't have much success writing an app.

Comment: Start with newboston tutorials series for Android. It's very good

Answer (score 1):

Things you want to be created when the activity is started should be in the onCreate method (buttons and onClickListeners etc). If for example you have a button you have stated an onClick name for in the xml file (rather than put an onClickListener on it) then you can put that function where you like as long as it is not after the last curly brace that finishes the activity. You should try the new boston tutorials on youtube, I found they explained a lot and helped me understand where I actually needed to put things.